# microsoft.office.interop.word deploy on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2003

I would like to convert Word Document to PDF on my local intranet Server  for my company. It Is a good idea to use microsoft.office.interop.word on my project instead of buying very expensive tools that don't support Arabic  at all.

I will be happy to hear an expert opinion about this case :)

Answer (score 2):

it depends on your need, Third party libraries would give lots of out of the box features whereas you would need to write a lot of code to achieve the same with [PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx). But if you need simple word doc to pdf conversion then PIA should do it for you.

But i would strongly recommend you to go for a wrapper assembly which would help to over come the disadvantages of using PIAs such as,

- They are limited to a version, i.e. they only work with one or
  certain versions of Office
- They cause problems while transferring or installation on other
  systems
- They offer no protection mechanism in the management of COM proxies

in a nutshell, if you are a using PIA your code might not work for different version of office whereas these wrapper assemblies manage multiple office versions using [Late Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding).

You can use [NetOffice](https://netoffice.codeplex.com/) which I have been using in projects for some time. some of the features of NetOffice are,

- Office integration without version limitations
- All features of the Office versions 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010,
  2013 are included
- Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop
  Assemblies

Answer (score 2):

I would not go as far to say that I am an expert here, but I can at least share my journey in hopes that it would save you time and energy.

This **can** work fairly reliably in limited scenarios, but Microsoft will tell you up front that:

*[InterOp on a Server] is not supported and will not scale well*

I agree, but for simple stuff... meh.

- Your first hurdle is having the correct rights to run interop. Where
  to run interop is a challenge for some companies. IMHO, I would not
  run it on my intranet server unless I could contain the process with
  limited rights (and yes that's doable).
- Your next challenge will be with virus's and the vulnerabilities of
  MS Word. MS Word must be kept up to date, customers must be able to
  deal with documents not getting converted (due to potential virus or 
  bad macros in the file).

The approach that I use is to run MS Word interop in a service or as a workflow. You need to expect to queue these requests and write your app as such. The service would work in the background and have limited rights other than to run MS Word, open a file and "Save As" PDF format (plus what ever other business logic you require). You would scale by adding more services/workflows on new servers (one interop service per machine)

When run in this manner, I have rarely had issues. I hope this helps.